# Create Web User Accounting System

Tags: user-controls, membership, login-script

I want to create a user accounting system for a web site that would allow people to create accounts and can then log in and log out. Could someone point me to a tutorial on the matter. Thanks.

Comment: What language/framework do you use?

Comment: http://www.lmgtfy.com/?q=php+authentication+tutorial